# Is it possible to clear the mock of a module in JEST?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to mock the function `forgotPassword` inside the module `authenticationPlugin/App`, So i am doing this

```
jest.mock("authenticationPlugin/App", () => ({
    forgotPassword (email: string) {
        const msg='success'
        email='a'
        return msg
    }
}))
```

Now i want to clear the mock of `authenticationPlugin/App` and have a different implementation for the `forgotPassword` method

So i did this

```
jest.clearAllMocks();
jest.mock("authenticationPlugin/App", () => ({
        forgotPassword (email: string) {
            throw new Error(<any>{'err':{'message':'Network Error'}})
        }
    }))
```

Now i expect the `forgotPassword` method to have a different implementation after clearing the mocks in for the module `authenticationPlugin/App` but it doesn't change...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different implementation for the mock in each test, you can use [`jest.fn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) instead.

Expanding on your code, it could look like this:

```
it('returns success', () => {
    authApp.forgotPassword = jest.fn((email: string) => {
        const msg='success'
        email='a'
        return msg
    });

    // Your test code here.
});

test('returns error', () => {
    authApp.forgotPassword = jest.fn((email: string) => {
        throw new Error(<any>{'err':{'message':'Network Error'}})
    });

    // Your test code here.
});
```